# Angular - Spans inside a div are not center aligned when using ngIf

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some code in AngularJS

It has 3 spans inside a div. Spans have ngIf. The problem is, if only **one** of the spans are displayed based on ngIf conditions, it is not center aligned. How to make it center aigned ?

```
<div class="text-center margin-top-tiny padding-top-xlarge" [hidden]="!showBalancePastDueOrFees">
  <div class="margin-top-tiny">
    <span class="padding-vert-small">
      <a class="button w-xtiny font-20 no-icon no-focus-effect text-center normal-weight" *ngIf="(isCashAcceptorAvailable && !hideCash)" (click)="checkFlowType(cashPaymentType)">{{msgCash | translate}}</a>
    </span>
    <span class="padding-vert-small">
      <a class="button w-xtiny font-20 no-icon no-focus-effect text-center normal-weight" *ngIf="(isCardReaderAvailable && !hideCreditDebit)" (click)="checkFlowType(creditdebitPaymentType)">{{msgCrDb | translate}}</a>
    </span>
    <span class="padding-vert-small">
      <a class="button w-xtiny font-20 no-icon no-focus-effect text-center normal-weight" *ngIf="(!hideGiftCard)" (click)="checkFlowType(giftCardPaymentType)">{{msgGc | translate}}</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the ngIf conditions here are set at ngOnInit(). for e.g. hideCreditDebit, hideGiftCard  are set to true at ngOnInt().

Comment: whats [hidden]   ?